# Eas build Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, eas

When i run the command build android on expo : eas build --platform android there is an error build :

> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

This is my eas.json :

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.4.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "base": {
      "node": "18.14.2"
    },
    "development": {
      "node": "18.14.2",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      },
      "android": {
        "image": "latest"
      },
      "channel": "development"
    },
    "preview": {
      "node": "18.14.2",
      "channel": "staging",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "image": "latest"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "node": "18.14.2",
      "channel": "production",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      },
      "android": {
        "image": "latest"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I am using expo 49, and managed workflow., the build works on ios but not on android. Also I ran expo doctor but there are no known issues. Did anyone have this issue ?